# How do I get the expiry date of an Azure AD access_token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token

I have a client application (a mobile app) that uses the Authorization Code flow to authenticate with Azure AD, the output of which is an ID Token and an access token.  I pass the access token to my private API via a bearer token as proof of authorisation, but I am unable to decode that token to be able to get its expiry time.

I know the API server can call the UserInfo endpoint to validate that access token, but I don't want to have to make that call every time my API is called, so ideally I want to get the expiry time of the token and use that to create a session token (cookie) for the API.

However, when I try to decode the access token with JWT tools (using the AzureAd public key), the result is clearly a JWT (and it contains my 'aud' field), but the payload has all the quote characters escaped, e.g. (snippet, with 'aud' obfuscated)
`{\"aud\":\"api://xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx\"\"iat\":1694613449,\"nbf\":1694613449,\"exp\":1694618100,`

Does anyone know how to handle this better? Can I get AzureAD to generate a JWT with a better payload? Can I get the expiry date from elsewhere?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is ridiculously embarrassing. I was extracting the access token from a logfile and pasting it into my code for decoding, as I haven't changed the API to support the bearer token yet, and it turns out that the print function that writes to the logfile had truncated the token! When I extracted the token from the debugger, it decoded just fine.

So I believe my original idea was correct - I can validate the access token against the UserInfo endpoint and then if valid, extract the exp field and use that to create a session cookie. When the client detects the original access token is due to expire, it can refresh it and send the new access token to the API, getting a new session token in response.

If this turns out not to work, I will come back and add any further comments.